# I need separe only the words from the array and put each word into an ArrayList. In this time, I can't use String tokenizer

Tags: java

*In this function, i try to separate the words. When the `for` cycle finds a space i try to put in ArrayList the word save in `token` (I use ASCII code to recognize uppercase and lowercase letters)*

```
public void separeWords(String Line){
        char [] line = Line.toCharArray();
        ArrayList TokensList = new ArrayList();
        String Character= "";
        
        for(int i=0; i<line.length; i++){
            if((line[i]>64 && line[i]<91) ||(line[i]>96 && line[i]<123)){
                    Character =  Character + String.valueOf(line[i]);
                
            }else if(Character.isWhitespace(line[i])==true){
                    TokensList.add(Character);
                    Character = "";
                }
        }
        
        System.out.println(TokensList);
    };
```

*I read a text file and next i call `separeWords` function, I send the String `line` like parameter*

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        PruebaAnalizador p = new PruebaAnalizador();
        
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file location"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            
            while(line != null){
                p.separeWords(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            
            reader.close();
                    
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**This is the content of the text file.**

```
public void AddRest(){
   int a = 5;
   int b = 3;
        
   System.out.println(a+b);
   System.out.println(a-b);
}
```

*Console Output:*

```
[public, void]
[, , , , , , , , int, a, ]
[, , , , , , , , int, b, ]
[, , , , , , , ]
[, , , , , , , ]
[, , , , , , , ]
[, , , ]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Instead of `line[i] == 32` try using `Character.isWhitespace(line[i])`.

Comment: I going to try with that method, thanks for your recomendation.

Comment: Not working yet.

Comment: In `separeWords`, you're using `Character` to refer to both a type (`java.lang.Character`) and a value `String Character = "";`. You want to call `java.lang.Character.isWhitespace(line[i])`, but you're instead trying to invoke an instance method named `isWhitespace` on a value of type `String`. Avoid using StartCase names for values, as it often causes this issue. To resolve, rename `Character` to something like `accumulator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class PruebaAnalizador {
  public void separeWords(String _line) {
    char[] line = _line.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<String> TokensList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String acc = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
      if (isAlpha(line[i])) {
        acc += String.valueOf(line[i]);
      } else if (Character.isWhitespace(line[i])) {
        // avoid adding empty strings for repeated whitespace
        if (acc != "") {
          TokensList.add(acc);
        }
        acc = "";
      }
    }

    // if the line ends in a word, make sure to add it!
    // (there won't be a whitespace after this line to
    // add it to TokensList inside the for loop)
    if (acc != "") {
      TokensList.add(acc);
    }

    System.out.println(TokensList);
  }

  private boolean isAlpha(char c) {
    return (c > 64 && c < 91) || (c > 96 && c < 123);
  }
}
```